# Crear función en tiempo de ejecución - PYTHON

Tags: python, sqlite, condiciones

Tengo una aplicación que trabaja con una base de datos en `SQLITE3`. He conseguido que a base de realizar algunas consultas a la base de datos, crear un *fichero.txt* con la estructura deseada. Esta estructura son una serie de `IFs` y `ELIFs` con condiciones en función de lo que haya en la base de datos. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero quería saber si es posible ese *fichero.txt*, guardarlo en formato **.py**, para que pueda ser llamado desde la aplicación inicial. No se si me explico correctamente, o será necesario *reiniciar* la aplicación ?

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podria hacer algo asi:

1.- Mi Txt(test.txt);

```
numero = 10    
if numero % 2 == 0:
 print "numero Par"
else:
 print "numero Impar"
```

2.- mi archivo Python desde donde leo el Txt y creo un nuevo archivo Python:

```
#abro el txt
docTexto = open("test.txt", "r")
#obtengo su contenido
contenidoTexto = docTexto.read()
#creo el archivo py
nuevo_nombre = 'contenidoTexto.py'
docNuevo = open(nuevo_nombre,"w+")
#escribo en el archivo py
docNuevo.write(contenidoTexto)
docNuevo.close()
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', nuevo_nombre])
```

finalmente tu resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función `exec` para ejecutar el código que define la función que comentas.
He creado un ejemplo en el cual la función que defino en el `template` se llama `fun`.

En este ejemplo hago uso de `jinja2` para generar el código a partir de un template. Finalmente y a modo de ejemplo ejecuto la función creada dinámicamente.

```
from jinja2 import Template

code_template = Template('''
def fun():
    if {{value}}:
        print('Hola Mundo')
''')

code = code_template.render(value = True)

exec(code)

fun()
```

Adicionalmente, podrías almacenar el template en un archivo, leerlo y crear el objeto template.

Cuando necesites regenerar el código, simplemente llamarías a `template.render()` pasándole las nuevas variables y volviendo a ejecutar el código mediante `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

No veo problema en hacerlo. Estos serian los pasos:

1. Abres el archivo en modo escritura
2. Lo editas con las funciones, condiciones, etc. garantizando la sintaxis de python
3. Lo guardas con extensión .py
4. Luego puedes usar `subprocess` para ejecutarlo desde python.

Esto sería en linux, no estoy seguro si en windows funciona igual `subprocess`.

Comment: Y si desde esa función a la que llamo con SUBPROCESS quiero acceder a variables que tengo en el proceso principal? Como debería hacerlo?

Comment: Hasta donde se, no se puede ya que es un programa diferente. Se me ocurre que al momento de editarlo podrias escribir como parte del archivo las varaiables y los valores que quieres usar. Pero una vez termine de ejecutarse, el programa principal sigue su curso con los valores que tenia. Debes tener claro que lo que tienes son dos archivos/programas en python **totalmente** independientes, uno creado dinamicamente por el otro.

Comment: Estoy viendo que existe la posibilidad de compartir variables con STDIN y STDOUT, mi idea es compartir un dataframe, hacerle unas modificaciones y devolverlo, es esto posible?

Comment: con STDIN y STDOUT estarias pasando "texto" como lo harias al ejecutar un programa desde consola. Desde mi perspectiva, creo que para lo que intentas hacer, debe haber otra forma más appropiada.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91967/crear-funcion-en-tiempo-de-ejecucion-python